# Position absolute related to an inline element

Tags: css, css-position

I want to have a word directly above another word in some longer text.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og7Lnmje/) doesn't achieve it (checked in Firefox and Chrome), "bar" position is not related to "foo", even though "foo" has `position: fixed`. To make things weirder, when I inspect the "bar" element in Firefox and turn off `position: absolute` and then turn it on again, "bar" moves above "foo", so it's clearly some undefined behavior.

Here's the fiddle's code:

```css
.node {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.tip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 12px;
  color: #c83025;
}
```

```html
aaaaaaa
<div class="node">
  foo
  <div class="tip">bar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` on `.node` (inline elements can't have `position: relative`, inline-blocks can)

```css
.node {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tip {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 12px;
    color: #c83025;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
aaaaaaa
<div class="node">
  foo
  <div class="tip">bar</div>
</div>
```

BTW: I added some code to center the absolutely positioned word in relation to its "parent word".

Comment: Thanks! This works as long as I'm okay with `display: inline-block`. I've found that using `left: 0` on `.tip` also seems to work, at least in Firefox and Chrome (which is enough in my case).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via `position: relative` and negative `margin-left` and `top`. Also instead of `top` you can use `transform: translateY` with some percentage like `transform: translateY(-100%)`.

Demo:

```css
body {
  /* just for demo */
  margin: 20px;
}

.node {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.tip {
  /* don't move to next line but allow margin-setting */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #c83025;
  top: -15px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

```html
aaaaaaa
<div class="node">
  foo
  <div class="tip">bar</div>
</div>
some other text
```